# How to change the event background color according to status

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am first time integrating the event calendar and I have successfully integrated everything, only one point where I am trapped is event background color is not changing. It is default set to `yellow`. I just want to change the background color of it.

Here is my code from where I am showing the data on event calendar.

```
showEvent(arg) {
      this.addingMode = false;
      const { id, title, start, end, desc } = this.events.find(
        event => event.id === +arg.event.id
      );
      this.indexToUpdate = id;
      this.newEvent = {
        event_name: title,
        start_date: start,
        end_date: end,
        description: desc,
      };
    },
```

And data is coming in it from,

```
public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'title' => $this->status,
            'start' => $this->start_date,
            'end' => $this->end_date,
            'desc' => $this->description,
        ];
    }
```

`event_name: title` is showing the status 0 or 1 on calender, I just want that where it is 0, it will show me yellow and where it is 1, it will show red.

Please help me out, I am poorly trapped in it,

Comment: When you use devtools to inspect your current state, do you have the correct data ? If not, you'll need to provide a larger code snippet so we can spot the error. It might propably come from somewhere else.

Comment: yes, I am getting the correct data like  <span class="fc-title">1</span>

Comment: or <span class="fc-title">0</span>

Comment: if you also atleast add an extra class with fc-title, then problem will solve.